# Integration of ZOHO CRM with MySQL using PHP...!

Tags: php, mysql, xml, curl, zoho

I have one problem in ZOHO CRM Developement.

Scenario:-I have account of ZOHO CRM.when i create Leads in my ZOHO CRM also at the same time the record will get created in MySQL Database(My Local Database) with same values and i want to do it using PHP Code style.so please suggest me a some solution on this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to analyze database structure of leads related tables and then prepare mysql query for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps.

- Get the data from zoho crm api using php, (php code for this available on google )
- Map crm data fields with mysql table fields
- Simply insert into mysql table.

You can upload your code at server and use in zoho as a webhook that trigger on record create event from zoho automation rule.